# Split Numpy array (800 * x) where each row is a string of space separeted feature values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a NumPy array of the form (3*1):

```
['1 2 3', '4 5 6 7 8 9', '10 11 12 13'].
```

Each row is a collection of feature values and each row has a different number of features. How can I split this array into multiple columns with each column representing a feature for all rows?

Update:
I am now using on DataFrames. So, I have a data frame with one column. Want to expand it and also convert it to integers. How can I do that?

[image]

Expectation: I want to split data in each row into multiple columns (features). Then, each column to numerics.

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  `expand=True` in `str.split` like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'features':['191 367 614 634 711',
                               '1202 1220 131 1730 2281 2572 2602 2611 2824', 
                               '2855 2940 3149 3313 3560 3568 3824 4185 4266']})

df.features.str.split(expand=True).astype(float).add_prefix('feature_')
```

Output:

```
   feature_0  feature_1  feature_2  ...  feature_6  feature_7  feature_8
0      191.0      367.0      614.0  ...        NaN        NaN        NaN
1     1202.0     1220.0      131.0  ...     2602.0     2611.0     2824.0
2     2855.0     2940.0     3149.0  ...     3824.0     4185.0     4266.0
```

Comment: How can I get NaN object here?

Answer (score 0):

Since numpy doesn't support non-rectangular arrays, it would be easiest to use pandas for this:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(l) for l in pd.Series(a).str.split(' ').tolist()], axis=1).T.add_prefix('feature_')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  feature_0 feature_1 feature_2 feature_3 feature_4 feature_5
0         1         2         3       NaN       NaN       NaN
1         4         5         6         7         8         9
2        10        11        12        13       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: what is "a" here?

Comment: `a` is your array, `['1 2 3', '4 5 6 7 8 9', '10 11 12 13']`

Comment: due to issue with NumPy only, I tried this:
trainData = trainDataInput.apply(lambda x: pd.concat([pd.Series(l) for l in x.str.split(' ').tolist()], axis=1)). But I got an error.

Comment: Ah, so you have a dataframe. Will you please post the results of `print(trainDataInput.head(2).to_dict())` to the question?

Comment: {'features': {0: '191 367 614 634 711 1202 1220 1311 1472 1730 2281 2572 2602 2611 2824 2855 2940 3149 3313 3560 3568 3824 4185 4266 4366 4409 4472 5008 5114 5408 5470 5509 5526 5626 5728 5910 5976 6031 6047 6069 6307 6352 6396 6401 6439 6468 6477 6708 6978 7092 7112 7149 7235 7470 74'}

Comment: Ok, try this instead: `pd.concat([pd.Series(l) for l in pd.Series(df['features']).str.split(' ').tolist()], axis=1).T.add_prefix('feature_')` (don't use it in a `.apply` call this time)

Comment: It switched the rows and columns.

Comment: Maybe you should specify your expected output from the dataframe in the question...

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please check? I have added an image also.

Answer (score 0):

You show a list (but the following also works if it's an array of strings):

```
In [44]: alist = ['1 2 3', '4 5 6 7 8 9', '10 11 12 13']
In [45]: alist
Out[45]: ['1 2 3', '4 5 6 7 8 9', '10 11 12 13']
```

Split each string into a list:

```
In [46]: blist = [s.split() for s in alist]
In [47]: blist
Out[47]: [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], ['10', '11', '12', '13']]
```

convert each number string to int:

```
In [48]: clist = [[int(x) for x in s] for s in blist]
In [49]: clist
Out[49]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Since the sublists differ in length, I'm going to refrain from processing this as arrays.  If you specify how such a list of lists maps on to your notion of features, we can proceed.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I have shifted to using DataFrame only. Arrays seemed a little complex.